# Duda java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Resulta que tengo que hacer un array de objetos de estudiantes (un estudiante tiene un nombre,apellido,comision,email,direccion)Cuando lo creo y lo recorro 
y lo imprimo llega a la parte de "Inserte un email" no me lo toma y salta directamente a la parte de "Inserte una direccion"

```
    vector=new Estudiante[2];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) {
        vector[i]=e;
        System.out.println("Inserte un nombre");
        String nombre=in.nextLine();
        vector[i].setNombre(nombre);
        System.out.println("Inserte un apellido");
        String apellido=in.nextLine();
        vector[i].setApellido(apellido);
        System.out.println("Inserte una comision");
        int comision=in.nextInt();
        vector[i].setComision(comision);
        System.out.println("Inserte un email");
        String email=in.nextLine();
        vector[i].setEmail(email);
        System.out.println("Inserte una direccion");
        int direccion=in.nextInt();
        vector[i].setDireccion(direccion);


    }

    int j;
    for(j=0;j<2;j++) {
        System.out.println("El nombre del estudiante es"+vector[i].getNombre());
        System.out.println("El apellido del estudiante es"+vector[i].getApellido());
        System.out.println("La comision del estudiante es"+vector[i].getComision());
        System.out.println("El email del estudiante es"+vector[i].getEmail());
        System.out.println("La direccion del estudiante es"+vector[i].getDireccion());


    }
```

Comment: El problema está en que antes de introducir un string (email), estás introduciendo un int y el buffer de entrada queda *sucio*. Antes de introducir el email, tendrías que añadir una línea con lo siguiente: `nextLine();`

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente una solución es lo que te indica Mario Guiber como comentario.

Doy por sentado, y supongo que Mario también, que usas un Scanner para la entrada de datos. Tal y como dice Mario, el buffer queda sucio ya que el método nextInt sólo devuelve el entero sin desechar el resto de la línea y cuando vuelves a acceder lee un retorno de carro que ha quedado en el buffer de la lectura anterior, por eso hace un salto ya que interpreta que has pulsado intro (CR). La clase Scanner no tiene ningún método explícito para la limpieza de su buffer (flush o similar).

También puedes utilizar el método parseInt de la clase Integer sin tener que hacer una doble llamada a next. Es otra alternativa:

```
int comision=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, lo pude solucionar. Me quedo una duda cuando mencionaste el tema del buffer, a que  hace referencia eso?

Comment: Scanner recibe la entrada del teclado mediante el argumento System.in. Sin entrar en detalles sobre la implementación, toda la entrada se almacena en una memoria intermedia (buffer). Sobre este buffer, Scanner divide la entrada en "trozos" (tokens) utilizando como delimitador el carácter espacio. Cuando utilizas nextLine, scanner devuelve todo el buffer, descartando el último carácter que corresponde con la tecla intro (retorno de carro ó CR). Cuando usas otro método como nextInt, scanner sólo utiliza el siguiente token, sin descartar el resto de lo que haya en el buffer, dejando un CR dentro.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta leer la linea y castearla a entero, a veces tengo esos problemas, creo que es por leer nextint y luewgo nextline

```
vector=new Estudiante[2];
int i;
for (i=0;i<2;i++) {
    vector[i]=e;
    System.out.println("Inserte un nombre");
    String nombre=in.nextLine();
    vector[i].setNombre(nombre);
    System.out.println("Inserte un apellido");
    String apellido=in.nextLine();
    vector[i].setApellido(apellido);
    System.out.println("Inserte una comision");
    int comision=Integer.valueOf(in.nextLine().trim());
    vector[i].setComision(comision);
    System.out.println("Inserte un email");
    String email=in.nextLine();
    vector[i].setEmail(email);
    System.out.println("Inserte una direccion");
    int direccion=Integer.valueOf(in.nextLine().trim());
    vector[i].setDireccion(direccion);


}

int j;
for(j=0;j<2;j++) {
    System.out.println("El nombre del estudiante es"+vector[i].getNombre());
    System.out.println("El apellido del estudiante es"+vector[i].getApellido());
    System.out.println("La comision del estudiante es"+vector[i].getComision());
    System.out.println("El email del estudiante es"+vector[i].getEmail());
    System.out.println("La direccion del estudiante es"+vector[i].getDireccion());


}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder!